# Training a Face Recognition model using benchmark datasets

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, image-recognition

Is it recommend (or conventional) to train, for instance a face recognition method, using benchmark datasets such as XQLFW, RFW, CALFW, etc.? I would like to fine tune my model so it is more robust to some variations and was wondering if I could use the datasets that I mentioned.